# I'd like to have my image filenames / paths when using Jest Snapshots

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I've started using [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) a lot in a new project, and I am now using the [Snapshot](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#snapshot-testing) functionality of Jest.

In a nutshell, what it does is render your components in a string, store that on disk (as a snapshot, that you can check-in in your repo), and when you run your tests later on it will compare that the snapshot didn't change.

My issue is to do with **importing images**:

The usual way to deal with that with Jest is to specify a handler for importing those, to mock them and return a random string.
That way, your tests won't have to actually load the image, it will just be mocked (otherwise you'll get exceptions, as Node doesn't know how to handle `import img from './image.png`, only Webpack does via a loader).

In the Jest configuration, you would do something like that:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/app/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    [...]
}
```

As you can see, images (png, jpeg, etc.) are all "resolved" using *fileMock*, which is simply this:

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

My issue here is that the mocking goes a bit too far: it always return the same string, which means my snapshots for a component that renders flag look like:

```
exports[`components - Flag should match the snapshot 1`] = `
<img
    alt="Flag"
    className="image"
    src="test-file-stub" />
`;
```

(the input was something like `<Flag country="fr" />`)

What I would like is my snapshot to be rendered as such:

```
exports[`components - Flag should match the snapshot 1`] = `
<img
    alt="Flag"
    className="image"
    src="/some/path/fr.png" />
`;
```

I don't believe I'm the only one facing this issue, but on the other hand I couldn't find any resource anywhere solving this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of relying on `moduleNameMapper` you can specify a custom `transform` where you return the image path instead of its source. A working example can be found under [Mocking CSS Modules](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules), pasting it below to make things easier.

```
// fileTransformer.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';
  },
};
```

and

```
// package.json (for custom transformers and CSS Modules)
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Link is dead. Now at https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules

Comment: When I use the shallow render of enzyme, I get src={ Object { "process": [Function], }  }

Comment: i also get `src={ Object { "process": [Function], } }` using storyshots

Comment: Anyone have any luck with this and shallow rendering?

Comment: Is there a way to get the full filepath instead of just the name of the file? My fileTransoformer just returns "image.png" instead of "path/to/image.png".

Comment: SVG should probably not be included (at least not for JSX/TSX source code).

Comment: @robert.bo.roth for me writing return `JSON.stringify(filename)` instead of `JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename))` worked

Answer (score 3):

Those having issues with `Valentin`'s suggestion and shallow rendering can try including this line within transform:

```
\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest"
```

so that it becomes:

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  }
}
```

The file `fileTransformer.js` remains the same!

> Note: Couldn't comment on his answer as I lack the 50 reputation to comment; this is my first answer here!