# Importing images breaks jest test

Tags: reactjs, testing, webpack, jestjs

In React components importing assets
    (ex, import logo from "../../../assets/img/logo.png)
gives such error

> ({"Object.":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){�PNG
>       SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
>         at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:305:17)

my jest config is

```
"jest": {
"testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.js$",
"moduleFileExtensions": [
  "js",
  "jsx",
  "json"
],
"moduleDirectories": [
  "node_modules",
  "src",
  "assets"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$/": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "\\.(css|less|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
},
"verbose": true,
"bail": true
}
```

what am i missing?

Comment: This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45044009/621690

Answer (score 163):

When you import image files, Jest tries to interpret the binary codes of the images as .js, hence runs into errors.

The only way out is to mock a default response anytime jest sees an image import!

#### How do we do this?

- first you tell Jest to run the mock file each time an image import is encountered. you do this by adding the key below to your package.json file

```json
"jest": {
 "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/fileMock.js"
    }
}
```

**Note**: if you already have the `"Jest"` key, just add the `"moduleNameMapper"` child in it

- lastly, create a `mocks` folder in your root and create `fileMock.js` file inside it.  populate the file with the snippet below

```js
module.exports = '';
```

**Note**: If you are using es6 you can use `export default '';` to avoid an Eslint flag

when you are done with the above steps, you can restart the test and ***you are good to go.***

**Note**. remember to add the varying extensions of your image files in the `moduleNameMapper` so that they can be mocked.

I hope I have been able to help. #cheers!

Comment: I've encountered the same issue even though  "moduleNameMapper" is set as you pointed out. You can see from the question that this is the case for the one who asked as well

Comment: I understand your point of view, but along the line, he may have done something the wrong way(perhaps, putting the `fileMocks.js` file in the wrong location or not having it at all). The exact reason why I reproduced a guide.
the bottom line is ensuring the files are named correctly and linked in the moduleNameMapper accordingly

Comment: it does not work for vue.js /typescript based tests

Comment: On mine the folder name is __mocks__

Comment: This worked for me only when i replaced `__mocks__` with `mocks`. My dir was named `mocks` and I presume jest couldn't find it. Thanks though!

Comment: Will just add in case in the fileMock.js this line solve everything for me =>
module.exports = {};

Answer (score 27):

For anyone looking into this problem. You have to do install `npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy` to get the necessary dependencies.

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

Comment: This was profoundly helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem and I solved it as follows:

1. `npm install -D jest-transform-stub`
2. Then, in package.json, I added the following transformation:

```
    "jest": {
        ...
        "transform": {
            ...
            ".+\\.(css|scss|png|jpg|svg)$": "jest-transform-stub"
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding bellow line into jest.config.js file helped me to test pass,

```
"\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
```

Example:

```
 moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue! I'm not sure if it's the same case as in the original question, but for me jest was still somehow trying to load the images as JS and trying to parse them while I had the files matching image extensions mapped to a mock in `moduleNameMapper`. My file also included some code to map the `@` character to the root src directory, since I had webpack and this was configured as a webpack alias in the project (and in TS). The full `moduleNameMapper` entry in `jest.config.js` looked like this for me:

```js
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@$': '<rootDir>/src',
        '^@/(.*)':
            '<rootDir>/src/$1',
        '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
        // '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
        '.*\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    }
```

For me it turned out that when I was importing the images in my components, the path was something like: '@/assets/someImage.jpg'. However, it seems this would match the first regex first, the one covering the `@` alias: `^@/(.*)`. Thus, it was being mapped to `<rootDir>/src/$1` instead of the `<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`.

I fixed it by making the alias only match non-images:

```js
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^@$': '<rootDir>/src',
        '^@/(.*)\\.(?!jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/src/$1',
        '.*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
            '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
        // '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
        '.*\\.(css|less)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use jest with webpack, you need to explicitly configure it as so. Take a look at this guide here: https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack

Comment: I'll add that you really need to create the `fileMock.js` and `styleMock.js` files.  I had a situation (which was specific to me) where I had created styleMock but not fileMock.  When I went to add my first image (png), then of course jest failed with exactly OP's error.  Because there was no file mock.  There seems to be an NPM package that helps with this but it only has 8 stars on github (now).

Comment: The OP mentions nothing about webpack, this issue is not related to the type of package manager used.

Answer (score 2):

For those who use `Vue test util` in `Nuxt 2` and are faced with question or this problem `({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){     SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

make a file with the name of `fileTransformer.js` in the `test/unit` directory, and then add these codes:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  process(src, filename, config, options) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';'
  },
}
```

and then add these codes to `jest.config.js` file:

```js
  transform: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
    '<rootDir>/test/unit/fileTransformer.js',
    // ... other configs
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy
```

and add the following inside your jest.config.js :

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
```

this worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

In case of IOS image names with `@`

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    "^image![a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+$": "GlobalImageStub",
    "^[@./a-zA-Z0-9$_-]+\\.(png|gif)$": "RelativeImageStub"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to transform that code into plain JavaScript so jest can read them.

create a jestFileTransform.js file in the root of your app and write a transformer inside the file:

```
const path = require('path')

 module.exports = {
 process(sourceText, sourcePath, options) {
  return {
   code: `module.exports = 
     ${JSON.stringify(path.basename(sourcePath))};`,
  }
 },
}
```

now use it in your jest config like this:

```
transform: {
'\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
  '<rootDir>/jestFileTransform.js',
'\\.(css|less|scss)$': '<rootDir>/jestFileTransform.js',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In React Native we use `preset: 'react-native'`

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/jest-preset.js

Or add `transform` into `jest.config.js`

```
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx)$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|mp4|png|psd|svg|webp)$': require.resolve(
      '../node_modules/react-native/jest/assetFileTransformer.js',
    ),
  },
```

If you do not use React Native, need to create a file https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/jest/assetFileTransformer.js into your project and changes path into `require.resolve`

Answer (score -1):

Nothing has worked for me, so I replaced
the 'mount' with 'shallow' everywhere and it's working fine now.