# Unit testing getting error for importing a png

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I've written a unit test for React. I ran the test and it failed with an error

```
import myLogo from "~/../img/myImage.png"
```

This code runs fine on the page and successfully renders the image. I am not sure why it fails on the Jest unit test.

Here is the error output

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../node_module/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

Comment: Did you read https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack?

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898638/importing-images-breaks-jest-test