# Error in render testing react native when require image

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-testing-library, react-native-image

I'm doing render testing of a login screen that returns an error when an image is on the screen and I don't know what to solve

test code

```
it('render screen Login ', () => {render(<Login />);});
```

return error

```
125 |             <Image
> 126 |               source={require('../../img/Login/facebook.png')}
      |                       ^
  127 |               style={styles.icon}
  128 |             />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80wMw.png)

Error text

Invalid return value:
`process()` or/and `processAsync()` method of code transformer found at
"F:/app/green1/node_modules/react-native/jest/assetFileTransformer.js"
should return an object or a Promise resolving to an object. The object
must have `code` property with a string of processed code.
This error may be caused by a breaking change in Jest 28:
https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest28#transformer
Code Transformation Documentation:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing images breaks jest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898638/importing-images-breaks-jest-test)

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the following [see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67054924/17866871)