# Local image import in nextjs with jest (react-testing-library) failed

Tags: next.js, integration-testing, babel-jest

I'm getting the below error while writing the test case against my home page, which contains the landing image.

```
    FAIL  src/test/unit/pages/home.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/xys/Documents/work/working/project-code/client/src/asset/images/landing/landing.png:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){�PNG
                                                                                      

    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

    > 1 | import LandingImage from '~/asset/images/landing/landing.png';
        | ^
      2 |
      3 | const Images = {
      4 |     LandingImage

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1796:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/asset/index.tsx:1:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.012 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

I have tried the below-suggested solution in jest.config.js file but unable to resolve this.

```
"\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/client/src/tests/unit/fileMock.js",
```

Also, I tried all the solutions suggested in the below site.

[Importing images breaks jest test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898638/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing images breaks jest test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898638/importing-images-breaks-jest-test)

Answer (score 0):

If you try to import an image (binary file), please try this within your package.json file:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/client/src/tests/unit/fileMock.js",
    }
  }
```

get more information in jest docs here: https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation