# What is console.error in react testing and is it okay to ignore?

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

I am on the way to learning Jest and React Testing Library. 
When I run the test below, it is 'passed' but I see the `console.error` message.

[sectionIntro.spec.js]

```js
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import SectionIntro from "../../components/home/SectionIntro.jsx";
import { CV_URL } from "../../lib/socials";

describe("SectionIntroComponent", () => {
  it("Should open the CV link when CV button is clicked", () => {
    render(<SectionIntro />);
    const cv_link = screen.getByText(/Check My CV/i);
    expect(cv_link.href).toBe(CV_URL);
  });
});
// Also a mock file is used for an image file.
```

[image]

[image]

[SectionIntro.jsx]

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import profilePic from "../../public/me.png";
import styles from "../../styles/SectionIntro.module.css";
import { CV_URL } from "../../lib/socials";

const SectionIntro = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>
          <Image
            className="rounded-full"
            src={profilePic}
            alt="The author of the website"
            objectFit="cover"
            sizes="30vw"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button
          className={`${styles.btnCV}`}
        >
          <a
            href={CV_URL}
            aria-label="CV"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Check My CV
          </a>
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SectionIntro;
```

[mocks/mockFile.js]

```js
export default "";
```

My question is if the test result is passed why the `console.error` is shown?
Would it be okay to ignore `console.error`? 
If it is not a good idea to hide the console, why is it so?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: It's usually fine but it's a good idea to figure out why the error is occurring. Are you seeing the same error in the browser console when running you app?

Comment: I don't see any errors on the browser console. I applied [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513338/18850353) to resolve the errors related to importing an image file. I guess the mockfile.js causes the console.error.

Comment: Can you post the source code as well?

Comment: @CathalMacDonnacha  I shared the codes for the related component and mockfile.js on the top. Thanks for your time!